# Create a SQL Trigger to reverse a previous Trigger

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, database-trigger

I am trying to create multiple triggers. One trigger updates the 'ysnAcknowledged' field when the (hidden) field 'Reprint' in the same form gets updated by Crystal Reports. The second trigger needs to update the 'Reprint' field if the 'ysnAcknowledged' field is manually updated by the user (form checkbox). I have the first trigger, my issue is if I update the 'ysnAcknowledged' field, it will trip my second trigger effectively reversing the first trigger before I want it to.

1st trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SOPickListReprint
ON dbo.SalesOrder
AFTER UPDATE
AS

IF UPDATE(Reprint)
UPDATE dbo.SalesOrder
SET ysnAcknowledged = 1
```

2nd Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SOPickListUpdate
ON dbo.SalesOrder
AFTER UPDATE
AS

IF UPDATE(ysnAcknowledged)
UPDATE dbo.SalesOrder
SET Reprint = 0
```

Comment: Do it in a Single trigger?  *(Also, bear in mind that more than one row can change, this trigger pretends only one row changes and then updates every row in the table?)*

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You are correct! This is MSSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SOPickListReprint
ON dbo.SalesOrder
AFTER UPDATE
AS

UPDATE dbo.SalesOrder
SET ysnAcknowledged = CASE WHEN deleted.Reprint = 0 AND inserted.Reprint = 1 THEN 1 ELSE inserted.ysnAcknowledged END,
Reprint = CASE WHEN deleted.ysnAcknowledged = 1 AND inserted.ysnAcknowledged = 0 THEN 0 ELSE inserted.Reprint END
FROM SalesOrder
INNER JOIN
inserted
    ON  inserted.SalesOrderID = SalesOrder.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN
deleted
    ON  deleted.SalesOrderID  = SalesOrder.SalesOrderID
```

Comment: Without the `WHERE` clause you will needlessly process *(and re-write)* rows where some other field changed.

Comment: @ MatBailie, you are correct. I will fix that now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER SOPickListUpdate
    ON dbo.SalesOrder
    AFTER UPDATE
AS

-- Update only rows where Reprint changed or ysnAcknowledged changed
-- > If ysnAcknowledged changed, force Reprint to 0, otherwise leave it as it is
-- > If Reprint changed, force ysnAcknowledged to 1, otherwise leave it as it is
UPDATE
    SalesOrder
SET
    Reprint         = CASE WHEN inserted.ysnAcknowledged <> deleted.ysnAcknowledged THEN 1 ELSE inserted.Reprint END,
    ysnAcknowledged = CASE WHEN inserted.Reprint         <> deleted.Reprint         THEN 0 ELSE inserted.ysnAcknowledged END
FROM
    SalesOrder
INNER JOIN
    inserted
        ON  inserted.<primary_key> = SalesOrder.<primary_key>
INNER JOIN
    deleted
        ON  deleted.<primary_key>  = SalesOrder.<primary_key>
WHERE
       inserted.ysnAcknowledged <> deleted.ysnAcknowledged
    OR inserted.Reprint         <> deleted.Reprint
```

Comment: @ MatBailie, I am working with only one table. Inserted and deleted have not been defined. I am not understanding how this is supposed to work.

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are meta-tables that SQL Server provides to you for use inside triggers.  I strongly recommend that you read the manual and/or some tutorials on SQL Server Triggers.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql  *(`[inserted]` contains every row INSERTED or UPDATED, `[deleted]` contains every row DELETED or UPDATED; An `UPDATE` being represented as a `DELETE` and then and `INSERT`...)*

Comment: thank you for your help! This is what I ended up doing: